# This this.userId() often null when calling from inside a meteor method

Tags: meteor

I recently started trying out the `auth` branch of meteor and depending where I call my meteor method that calls this.userId(), it will return null or the user id that I need.

To be a little more specific, it works when my meteor method is called from a coffeescript class initialized inside of Meteor.startup, but *not when that same method is called from inside Meteor.publish*.

The meteor method is simple and probably not relevant, but just in case:

```
Meteor.methods(
  get_user_id: ->
    return @userId()
)
```

EDIT: It seems people were not able to reproduce my problem, here is a patch on the todo auth example that should demonstrate it.

```diff
    diff --git a/examples/todos/server/methods.js b/examples/todos/server/methods.js
    index e69de29..d4182a6 100644
    --- a/examples/todos/server/methods.js
    +++ b/examples/todos/server/methods.js
    @@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
    +Meteor.methods({
    +  get_user_id: function() {
    +    console.log(this.userId());
    +    return this.userId();
    +  }
    +});
    diff --git a/examples/todos/server/publish.js b/examples/todos/server/publish.js
    index 1552c5e..87cb29f 100644
    --- a/examples/todos/server/publish.js
    +++ b/examples/todos/server/publish.js
    @@ -16,6 +16,8 @@ Todos = new Meteor.Collection("todos");

     // Publish visible items for requested list_id.
     Meteor.publish('todos', function (list_id) {
    +  Meteor.call('get_user_id');
    +  //console.log(this.userId())
       return Todos.find({
         list_id: list_id,
         privateTo: {
```

---

thanks [Eitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1481033/eitan) for the patch!

Comment: I'm not sure that `Meteor.call` is intended to be used server-side? I'm unsure but that is probably the problem here.

Comment: @TomColeman -- check the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) if you don't believe me.

Comment: yep, I guess this is a bug then. I guess you should open an issue on github and let the devs know. Obviously the auth branch is unreleased code at this point...

Comment: great, thanks! I just wanted to be sure before I opened an issue.

Comment: perhaps duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576136/how-to-get-this-userid-in-function-inside-meteor-method/30576355#30576355

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Meteor.userId()` to retrieve the current user's ID within `Meteor.methods`. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be stupid: **But, are you logged in?** (Sorry, this was my problem finally.)

---

So best might be to check first if logged in:

```
if (this.userId)
    console.log(this.userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.userId()` is on its own not reactive as far as I am aware of, so if you want other things to react on it you will need to put it inside a `Session` variable. So, from `Meteor.startup` you do:

```
Session.set('userId', this.userId());
```

Then, where you need it you can use this instead:

```
Session.Get('userId');
```

That way, when it is missing and thus `null` it will be filled in later.

Comment: I don't think that is my problem, I said the class was initiated from inside of startup, but the function is called regularly and there is no expectation of reactivity.

Comment: That's defeating the concept of Meteor though, you'd want things to be reactive rather than calling a function regularly; and if still proceed with that, why not check if it is null and in such case skip the execution until the next time the function is called.

Comment: I think you miss understood, I'm hooking the class in to the reactivity somewhere else but it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Are you sure that you are getting the return value of the `Meteor.call` properly? Something like:

`Meteor.call 'get_user_id', (error, result) -> console.log(result)`

What happens if you add `console.log(@userId())` in your method?

Comment: The null result is coming from a log inside the meteor method.

Comment: I will try to make a patch for the todo example to help reduce the problem.