# How to get this.userId in function inside Meteor method

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

I need to call a few times a function for every user who is logged in, but when the function is placed inside meteor method, this.userId becomes undefined inside function scope, here's the example:

```
myMethod: function(){

  console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId

  function innerFunction(){
    console.log(this.userId); // this returns undefined
  };
  innerFunction();

}
```

How can I pass this.userId inside a function?
Does a function has to be binded with Meteor.bindEnvironment?

Comment: Have you tried writing it as `Meteor.userId()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some variants to resolve this:

- use `.bind()` method:

  ```
  myMethod: function () {
   console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId

   function innerFunction() {
       console.log(this.userId); // this returns undefined
   }

   innerFunction.bind(this);
  }
  ```
- use `.apply()` method for applying correct`this` into function:

  ```
  myMethod: function () {
   console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId

   function innerFunction() {
       console.log(this.userId); // this returns undefined
   };

   innerFunction.apply(this);
  }
  ```
- also you can just use `that` insted of `this`for pass the scope into in `innerFunction`:

  ```
  myMethod: function () {
      var that = this;
      console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId

      function innerFunction() {
         console.log(that.userId); // this returns undefined
      }

      innerFunction();
  }
  ```
- or just pass userId into `innerFunction`

  ```
  myMethod: function () {
    var userId = this.userId;
    console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId

    function innerFunction(userId) {
        console.log(userId); // this returns undefined
    }

    innerFunction();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid adding userId as a function argument, but other solutions are exactly what i was looking for, especially a .bind(this) solution which has the simplest syntax.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski I've really glad that my solution helps you :)

Comment: A .bind() solution returns error unexpected token . which has something to do with this dot after { ... }, but since everyone mentioned this solution it may be kind of local problem, but I checked innerFunction.apply(this); and works with no problems.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski aah.. yes exactly. I've made changes in answer for ```.bind()```

Comment: after change from .apply to .bind function is not starting at all, but does not throw any errors and server is starting, in fact now .bind and .apply solution look very close, so I will stick up with .apply solution, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do it:

```
myMethod: function () {
    var me = this;

    function innerFunction () {
        console.log(me.userId);
    };

    innerFunction();
}
```

or

```
myMethod: function () {
    var innerFunction = function () {
        console.log(this.userId);
    }.bind(this);

    innerFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to bind the function ?

```
   myMethod: function(){

      console.log(this.userId); // this returns proper userId


  function innerFunction(){
    console.log(this.userId); // this returns undefined
  }.bind(this);
  innerFunction();

}
```

Comment: this code couldn't be work, because ```.bind()``` should executes like ```innerFunction.bind(this)```